# Image Folder icon as stack of images similar to IPad

Tags: xcode

I have been searching all over but I am unable to solve my problem. I have folder with only images in it. I want to set the icon of that folder as the stack of images with top image being the first image in the folder similar to the icons we have in IPad photo gallery. I have attached an example S[image: Stack Icon]

Please tell how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following control can help you

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/swsnapshotstackview

Comment: @SurbhitThanvi I have not implemented the code so sorry for that, but I think now you can get some idea from this project.